# getting bad request (400) from running pod in kubernetes! whats the problem?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to `kubernetes`. I installed `kubernetes` on my local machine on `minikube` context. I created deployment using this config file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: currency-deploy-1
  labels:
    first_deploy_key : first_deploy_value
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      first_deploy_key : first_deploy_value
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        first_deploy_key : first_deploy_value
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: currency-img
          image: smmiri01/currency_img:2
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
```

and created a service based on this config file:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: currency-service
spec:
  selector:
    first_deploy_key: first_deploy_value
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8001
    targetPort: 8000
  type: NodePort
```

when I run `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> bash` and run `curl localhost:8000` get the result and every things work fine. but outside the `pod` I run `minikube service <service-name>` get `Bad Request (400)`!

I replaced `port` by `nodePort` parameter and it raises an error when I want to create a new service:

```
error: error validating "currency_service.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.ports[0]): missing required field "port" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

and when I set `nodePort=30001`, `port: 8000` and `targetPort: 8000` it still get me bad request error! the error is as below:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.99.100:30001/
*   Trying 192.168.99.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100) port 30001 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.99.100:30001
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Sun, 10 Jul 2022 08:28:00 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.13
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Connection: close
< 

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bad Request (400)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

I don't know how to debug the application. what should I do?

Comment: Seems like you get a response from your app.  You have to check your code under what circumanstances it would repond with 400.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is not configured correctly. You need to remove the `port: 8001` parameter and add `nodePort: 8001` instead. After this, your service will:

1. Receive incoming traffic on `port: 8001`.
2. Forward the traffic to the listening pods on `targetPort: 8000`.

The `port` parameter is for `ClusterIP` and `LoadBalancer` service types.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I cannot remove port parameter, it raise an error. but I added nodePort parameter and still get the bad requests

Comment: you can simply delete the service object that exists already and create a new one with the changes.

Comment: I did, I removed the old one and create a new service with new config but when I remove port parameter it raise an error and cannot create a new service.

Comment: Oh, then you can try setting `port: 8000`, `targetPort: 8000` and `nodePort: 8001`. does that work?

Comment: I set `port: 8000`, `targetPort: 8000` and `nodePort: 30001` but that still get me bad request!

Comment: Can you show the exact error message? (update the question)

Comment: Thanks, Also, the exact error message for `bad request`.

Comment: I sorry! how can I get full message of bad request?
I can only use `curl` and get the `bad request 400`

Comment: You can use verbose version `curl localhost:8000 --verbose`. Also, could you try and use the node IP instead of localhost in your curl? 
You can run `kubectl get nodes` and note the node name (probably minikube) use `minikube ip <node nam>` to get the IP address of the node. You can then curl <nodeIP:8001>.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246309/discussion-between-mohammad-and-zer0).

Comment: sure. let's do that.